# Get variable with selected option c#

Tags: c#, razor

What I'm trying to do is to get the value of the selected option on my Dropdown list to use it in my tbody but I don't know how to do that. This is my code

```html
<select id="pdvlist" class="ctl-source" onchange="return item">
    <option value=" ">Todos</option>
                                             
    @foreach (var item in Model.Select(l => l.Pdv).Distinct() )
    {
        <option value="@item">@item</option>
    }
</select>
```

This is the part of my body where i need the value of the selecteditem to make a filter.

```html
<tbody>
 @string pdvId = pdvlist.Value.ToString();
 
 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {
  var total = 0;
  decimal costo = 0;

  for (int i = 1; i <= 28; i++)
  {
   var value = 0;
   if (item.Fecha.Day == i) { value = item.Cantidad; costo = costo + item.Total; }
   total += value;
  }
  <tr>
   <td>@item.Descripcion</td>
   <td>@((costo / total).ToString("C"))</td>
   @for (int i = 1; i <= 28; i++)
   {
    var value = 0;
    int month = item.Fecha.Month;
    if (item.Fecha.Day == i) { value = item.Cantidad; }
    <td>
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="popover"
        data-html="true" data-original-title="@i/@month/2015" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Producto: @item.Descripcion<br />PV:@((costo / total).ToString("C"))<br />Total:@value<br />Venta:@(((costo / total) * value).ToString("C"))" data-trigger="hover">@value</a>
    </td>
   }
   <td>@total</td>
   <td>@(((costo / total) * total).ToString("C"))</td>
  </tr>
 }  
</tbody>
```

Comment: You need to explain more here.  For example you are trying to get the value "to use it in my"... what?  In your controller?  In some other part of your page?  Also, what you have given us is insufficient to reproduce whatever your problem is.  Please edit your question to make this more clear or it will be nearly impossible to help you.

Comment: You've got a lot understanding to overcome based on this code snippet. You're onchange handler is trying to reference a server side variable from JavaScript. If you look at the html resulting from this there is no foreach loop, you just see all of the options rendered.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Becuzz i had to edit my post since some part where cut off, what im trying to make is get the selected value of my option to the be able to use it for a filter like i put in    @string pdvId = pdvlist.Value.ToString(); using the selecter id but i cant make a statement out of my pdvId String

Comment: Are you trying to make that table that changes based on what someone selects in the dropdown?  If so, you need to do that with Javascript, not C#.  The C# code runs on your server and renders the page.  That page gets sent to the client's browser as is.  There is no more C# code in that page anymore.  Javascript can be rendered as part of the page and it can affect things.

Comment: thanks i need to look for a javascript aproach just as you said i was making the  wrong aproach to the problem